# Calculate difference between higher date and lower date in Excel where the dates are in two different rows having one common factor

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Example:

```
                     Row A     Row B

Col A: - AMS Alert   1-sep12   1-sep12

Col B: - AMS Alert   4-sep12   4-sep12
```

Now I want to calculate turn around time for task AMS Alert where I need Excel to take higher date (minus) lower Date, Meaning i want excel to calculate 4<sup>th</sup> Sep 12 (Minus) 1<sup>st</sup> Sep 12 = 3 Days.

I have around 5,000 such records and doing this manually is impossible. Is there any formula to do so?

Comment: Are your Col/Row labels the wrong way round...???

Answer (score 1):

Are the dates strings or are they (formatted) date values? If they're dates, you can simply calculate the difference between `MAX()` and `MIN()` of the two values (`=MAX(A1:B1)-MIN(A1:B1)`), otherwise you should turn convert them into date values first.

Comment: The values are date values,, but the porblem is sometimes i have 10-12 similar rows but the dates in column changes ,,, how the fomula will consider which is the higher date and which is the lower date?????

Comment: See updated answer. If that doesn't help, please update your question with a more representative sample of your data.